# envelopidstamping in the SOAP API

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to remove the envelope id stamp from documents produced via the Docusign API (using SOAP). The account is set to not show stamps, the templates are set to not show stamps (Support have checked all that - ref 01414181) and I am setting envelopidstamping to false in the C# when creating the envelope in the API call, but the setting is lost before the request leaves our server, and in the response from DS it is set to true.

I have never seen this before, where a valid web service parameter is stripped before the XML is built and sent.

There is another field showing as available for use in the API call, envelopeIdStampingFieldSpecified, but I can’t find any information at all as to what, if anything, it does. Do I need to use that? Why is it not mentioned in any documentation?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get an answer without posting a bit of code that reproduces your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including/setting both properties in the request -- but set the *Specified* property to **true**:

```
 <envelopeIdStampingField>false</envelopeIdStampingField>
 <envelopeIdStampingFieldSpecified>true</envelopeIdStampingFieldSpecified>
```

Including the **envelopeIdStampingFieldSpecified** property in the request (set to **true**) should result in the **envelopeIdStampingField** property be included in the XML that's sent out over the wire.

**Note**: The use of *Specified* properties like this isn't specific to only the DocuSign API -- this same requirement exists for some properties of other SOAP APIs as well...it's an artifact of how those properties are defined in the XML schema. Anytime you're specifying a property value in a SOAP API request, but that value's not actually being included in the data that's sent out over the wire, the first thing you should check is whether or not there's a corresponding *Specified* property -- if so, set the corresponding *Specified* property to **true**.

Comment: Thanks a lot - works perfectly. Would be nice if it was mentioned in the documentation, but that's not your fault.